# Show the output of a $(shell xx ) command also on stdout

Tags: gnu-make

I have an external program creating the a bunch of files. These files are prerequisites to my targets.
At the moment I call it as follows:

```
# build the external resouce and create a the file filelist.txt
VHDL_SOURCES += $(shell make -C $(SCRIPT_PATH) > $(SCRIPT_PATH)/log; cat $(BUILD_PATH)/filelist.txt)
```

This works fine. My variable VHDL_SOURCES contains all source files mentioned in filelist.txt.
The drawback of this approach is that I can not see the output of the called script. As it takes a long time to run, it would be great to see on the stdout whats going on.

Is there a way to show what is moved (and therefore hidden) to $(SCRIPT_PATH)/log at the moment?

Comment: I think you're looking for the `tee` command.

Comment: Where would I then send the pipe to? Is there a variable or a handle to access the STDOUT of the calling make file?

Instead of using "tee" I can also remove $(SCRIPT_PATH)/log and send the output to the STDOUT. But exactly this is the problem: How can I get a handle to makes stdout?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the problem statement. Let me suggest a different approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything from `$(shell ...)` stdout [goes into its result](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Shell-Function.html#Shell-Function). You cannot let it go to stdout, and then take some other stdout as a function result.

You can redirect the script's output to stderr. This may or may not be suitable, depending on how you use your makefile.

Let me suggest a more dramatic change.

Calling recursive `make` from `$(shell)` is a sign of an overcomplicated process. Let's at least make it idiomatic: let's [generate an `include`d makefile](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Prerequisites.html#Automatic-Prerequisites) with a proper value. This will rebuild it if it's not present.

```
include $(BUILD_PATH)/filelist.mk

$(BUILD_PATH)/filelist.mk:
     # A normal recursive call. Its output goes to stdout.
     make -C $(SCRIPT_PATH)
     # Assuming that filelist.txt can only include a list of 
     # existing files, and no malicious injected code.
     echo "define VHDL_SOURCES" > $@
     cat $(BUILD_PATH)/filelist.txt >> $@
     echo "endef" >> $@
```

- Bonus: if you can set a proper dependencies for `filelist.mk`, it will only be rebuilt when these dependencies change.
- If you want it to always rebuild (which is probably not necessary), make it [phony](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Phony-Targets.html):

  ```
  .PHONY: $(BUILD_PATH)/filelist.mk
  ```
- After the file is generated, `make` will restart its run with the new included file.